# No me funcionan las decisiones usando HashTable c#

Tags: c#

sucede que estoy creando un pequeño programa de inicio sesión para una tarea de la universidad, el objetivo es crear un inicio sesión usando *HashTables*. Al momento de el usuario ingresar su **cédula**(Documento de identidad) deberia iniciar sesion si esta es correcta.

Lo primero que hice fue crear una variable llamada **cedula_empleado**, luego de esto coloqué un **input** para que al momento de ingresar la cédula que está en el *HashTable*, si esta es correcta al ser ingresada, deberia de mostrar el nombre del empleado que esta en el *HashTable*, asi como tambien si la cuenta esta **activa** o **inactiva** y la **fecha de creación**

El problema sucede cuando voy a introducir la **cédula**, al momento de la decisión hacer su análisis da por hecho que la cédula ingresada es incorrecta, algo que no debería ser así.

Intenté convertir los datos a *String* pero no funcionó puesto que obviamente son datos *String*.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace PRACTICA_FINAL
{
  internal class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      Hashtable empleado_1 = new Hashtable();
    

      //EMPLEADO 1 HASHTABLE
      empleado_1.Add(1, "JUAN ALBERTO GARCIA GALVAN");
      empleado_1.Add(2, "40213664937");
      DateTime empleado1_creacion = new DateTime(2008, 5, 1);
      empleado_1.Add(3, "ACTIVA");

      //INPUT
      string cedula_empleado;
      Console.Write("Ingrese su numero de cédula: ");
      cedula_empleado = Console.ReadLine();

      //DECISION 
      if (cedula_empleado == empleado_1[2])
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido a la plataforma Sr. " + empleado_1[1]);
              Console.WriteLine("Su cuenta está: " + empleado_1[3] + " y fue creada el {0}", empleado1_creacion);
            }
            else
            {
              Console.WriteLine("CEDULA EQUIVOCADA");
            }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Probaste debuguear a ver que valor hay en la variable y tambien en la hashtable?

Comment: Hey, hola muchisimas gracias por la ayuda ya que soy nuevo aqui, bueno logre resolver el problema con una cosa muy simple, definiendo el string en la decision de la siguiente manera. if (cedula_empleado == (string) empleado_1[2])

Comment: Por favor, no edites tu publicacion y pongas solucionado ni nada asi. La solucion debe ir explicada en el campo respuesta. Si no sabes porque fue resuelto de esa forma, investiga y nos cuentas ;). Voy a volver atras tu publicacion.. te pido que leas los enlaces que te pase para que veas como funcionamos.. No somos un foro como los que tal vez conoces...

Comment: Okay, entiendo, gracias por dejarme saber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es correcto lo de convertir a `string` en la comparacion del `if` para definir correctamente los tipos de datos

Pero creo que implementas de forma incorrecta el uso del `HashTable`, la key deberia ser el numero de cedula y el value el resto de los datos

Deberias crear una class que represente al empleado

```
public class Empleado
{
    public string nombre {get; set;}
    public DateTime creacion {get; set;}
    public bool activa {get; set;}
}
```

Para luego aplicar

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Hashtable listaEmpleados = new Hashtable();

    Empleado empleado1 = new Empleado()
    {
        nombre = "JUAN ALBERTO GARCIA GALVAN",
        creacion = new DateTime(2008, 5, 1),
        activa = true
    };

    listaEmpleados.Add("40213664937", empleado1);


    Console.Write("Ingrese su numero de cédula: ");
    string cedula_empleado = Console.ReadLine();

   
    if (!listaEmpleados.ContainsKey(cedula_empleado))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CEDULA EQUIVOCADA");
        return;
    }

    Empleado empleado = listaEmpleados[cedula_empleado];
    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido a la plataforma Sr. " + empleado.nombre);
    Console.WriteLine("Su cuenta está: {0} y fue creada el {0}", empleado.activa, empleado.creacion);

}
```

Valida como se usa el `ContainKey()` para validar si una key del hastable coincide, ya la cedula es la key

Comment: Si, muy bien explicado, me funcionó de esa forma, gracias

Comment: @AlejandroMatos marca la respuesta como aceptada: click en check verde :D